# Android ParseFacebookUtils flow with login and logout

Tags: android, parse-platform, parsefacebookutils

I've implemented a Parse & Facebook flow in my Android app using ParseFacebookUtils.

**TL;DR**

1. Created a Parse user after logging in (and linking) with Facebook
   (ParseFacebookUtils.logIn)
2. Logged out (ParseFacebookUtils.logOut &
   ParseUser.logOut)
3. Logging in again with Facebook creates a new Parse
   user instead of fetching the old one.

**Longer version**: The login flow works - the ParseFacebookUtils.logIn call launches the Facebook dialog and after accepting a new Parse user is being created and linked to the user's Facebook account.

The problems arises after logging out (ParseFacebookUtils.logOut and ParseUser.logOut), and trying to log back in to the same Parse user. The Facebook dialog shows up briefly then I'm getting redirected to the app (as it's already authorized for that Facebook user), but it seems like a new Parse user is being created instead of finding the previous one for the relevant Facebook user.

**Question**: Is there a way to enable such flow? Would I have to get the already created user manually?

The code for my **MainActivity**, in which all the login logic reside:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private ProgressBar progressBar;
  private Button loginButton;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_loading_spinner);
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.splash_facebook_login);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        onLoginButtonClicked();
      }
    });

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    // Check if there is a currently logged in user
    // and they are linked to a Facebook account.
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if ((currentUser != null) && ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
      // load data from Parse user and launch the next activity immediately
      retrieveData();
    } else {
      failedLoggingIn();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

  // this method will link the current ParseUser to the used Facebook account if needed
  private boolean linkFacebookUser() {
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    // save fb_id and email to the parse user
    Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(GraphUser fbUser, Response response) {
        if (fbUser == null) {
          Log.e("Facebook Me Request", "Failed fetching user Facebook Graph object.");
        } else {
          Log.d("Facebook Me Request", "Received Facebook graph object for "+fbUser.getId()+"("+fbUser.getProperty("email").toString()+")");

          ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("fb_id", fbUser.getId());
          ParseUser.getCurrentUser().setEmail(fbUser.getProperty("email").toString());
          ParseUser.getCurrentUser().setUsername(fbUser.getProperty("email").toString());
          ParseUser.getCurrentUser().setPassword(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
          ParseUser.getCurrentUser().signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
              if (e == null) {
                Log.d("Parse signup user", "Successfully saved a new Parse-Facebook user!");
                retrieveData();
              } else {
                Log.e("Parse signup user", "FAILED saving a new Parse-Facebook user. Error: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }).executeAsync();

    return true;
  }

  private void retrieveData() {
    // fetch data needed to show movie recommendations
    Log.d("Parse Facebook Login Info", "fb_id=" + ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("fb_id"));

    startActivity(new Intent(this, BrowseMoviesActivity.class));
    finish();
  }

  private void failedLoggingIn() {
    ParseUser.logOut();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

  private void onLoginButtonClicked() {
    Log.d("UI", "Clicked the Facebook login button");
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList(
      "public_profile",
      "user_friends",
      "user_actions.video",
      ParseFacebookUtils.Permissions.User.EMAIL,
      ParseFacebookUtils.Permissions.User.ABOUT_ME,
      ParseFacebookUtils.Permissions.User.RELATIONSHIPS,
      ParseFacebookUtils.Permissions.User.BIRTHDAY,
      ParseFacebookUtils.Permissions.User.LOCATION
    );

    ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, this, new LogInCallback() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
        MainActivity.this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (user == null) {
          Log.d("ParseFacebookLogin", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
          if (err != null) {
            Log.d("ParseFacebookLogin",  "Error: " + err.getLocalizedMessage());
          }

          failedLoggingIn();
        } else if (user.isNew()) {
          Log.d("ParseFacebookLogin", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
          // we should probably use this scenario to set fb id to the Parse user
          linkFacebookUser();
        } else {
          Log.d("ParseFacebookLogin", "User logged in through Facebook!");
          if (user.get("fb_id") == null) {
            linkFacebookUser();
          } else {
            retrieveData();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest opening a detailed bug report at developers.facebook.com.  I don't think this behavior is expected.

Comment: When you say "it seems like a new Parse user is being created", what makes you think that? Are you debugging the user, perhaps log the ID of the user so you can verify if it is the same or new?

Comment: @TimothyWalters exactly. I'm saving the FB id on first creation, and it is not set following the detailed flow. Also, the Parse user cannot be saved - I get an error that I must signUp first.

Comment: As @Fosco said then, file a bug report: https://parse.com/help

Comment: If you're getting an error that you must sign up, then I bet in your code you're creating a ParseUser object and setting fields on it. Provide your code.

Comment: @Fosco: It's the basic code example provided at https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-android and I've made sure of that again that there isn't anything special. Inside the logInCallback I'm checked if it's a new user, and if so I use the signUp method to set all the required fields and an fb_id field. At that point, everything works ok, the Parse user is created and it  is linked properly to my Facebook ID. Then, after a logOut, trying to logIn succeeds, but now the Parse user is a fresh new user - which leads to trying to signUp again, which obviously fails.

Comment: @Fosco: Am I missing something about the flow? Shouldn't it be used like this?

Comment: in the login callback you already have the user, whether they are new or not, so you wouldn't want to call signUp again, only set fields/save.  Please add actual code.

Comment: @Fosco: Alright, added the code now

Comment: yeah, don't signUpInBackground... saveInBackground.

Comment: @Fosco: but that leads to, as I thought, `com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser until it has been signed up. Call signUp first.`. By what I understand from what you say, ParseFacebookUtils should have created the new Parse user with the Facebook account attached to it, and should have saved it by itself. Checking the web data browser I can see that a new user was -not- created during this process.
Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: is currentUser null?...

Comment: @Fosco: Checked just before calling saveInBackground, and no, `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` is NOT null. (if it was, my call to `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground()` would have failed for a different reason :))

Comment: Though, it is null -before- the logIn method (as expected, I would assume)

Comment: Then back to my original suggestion... open a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Actually it was a bug in parse sdk and the problem was solved without changing any of my code, just by installing the latest parse android sdk(1.8.1 at the time of writing).